# Node.js redirecting style and resource folder based on subdomain

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have this server.js file that creates a localserver.

```
//server.js
var connect = require('connect');
connect.createServer(
  connect.static(__dirname)
).listen(8080);
```

It uses the node package connect to start a localhost on the same dirname where my webapp is. I would like to extend this code so I can have a subdomain.

When I place the address localhost:8080/companyA I want the link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

to be redirected to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="companyA/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
```

so resuming. I want my website to be styled according to the subdomain. Only the resource folder will be redirected.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

**NOTE: I would like to keep the index file plain without using a template for it or a markup language. Basically I should be able to achieve that using some routing rules.**

Answer (score 1):

You can address the redirect using Jade markup language.  For example

```
app.get('/:company/path', function(req, res){
    var subdomain = req.params.company;
    res.render('myview', {subd: subdomain});
});
```

now inside the view, myview.jade

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href=#{subd}/css/bootstrqp.css, type="text/css")
```

another option is to accomplish the redirect solely in the route

```
app.get('/:company/css/:file', function(req, res){
    var options = {
        root: __dirname + '/public/' + req.params.company,  // wherever your css files are located
        dotfiles: 'deny',
        index: false
        headers: {
            'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
            'x-sent': true
        };
    };

    res.sendFile(req.params.file, options, function(err){
       // css files sent. hooray!
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks takinola, the thing is I would like to keep the index as it is without using templates/markup language language.

Comment: There is a way to accomplish what you want but it would require foregoing using static file serving and writing routes for the css files.  Would this be a reasonable approach for you?

Comment: this would be a good start. Could you write an small example for a routing rule addressing the css?